# Error on Skeleton Markers

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I follow the instruction on Skeleton Markers h*ttp://wiki.ros.org/skeleton_markers. Sorry I do not have the right to publish a link, but that package is so cool.

However I encounter some problems (ROS Hydro + Ubuntu 12.10).

When I install it, on command git checkout hydro-devel, it says
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /home)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
I do not know what does it mean. But I can catkin_make the package...

After installation, I try to run it. however the first method does not work for me, while the second method works well.

UPDATE
It works by following answers below. Thank you very much @Pi Robot. However there is a warning. I think it relates to the depth registration. You know, I cannot display registered RGB D image right now. As show in http://answers.ros.org/question/143871/no-register-data-from-kinect/ The log of catkin_make skeleton markers is listed below. The warning is in the last four lines.

rical@rical-CF-19RHRAX1M:~/ros_kinect$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/rical/ros_kinect
Source space: /home/rical/ros_kinect/src
Build space: /home/rical/ros_kinect/build
Devel space: /home/rical/ros_kinect/devel
Install space: /home/rical/ros_kinect/install

##### Running command: "cmake /home/rical/ros_kinect/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/rical/ros_kinect/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/rical/ros_kinect/install" in "/home/rical/ros_kinect/build"

-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/rical/ros_kinect/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/hydro
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/hydro
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/rical/ros_kinect/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- catkin 0.5.81
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - skeleton_markers
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'skeleton_markers'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(skeleton_markers)
-- Found GLUT: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglut.so
-- skeleton_markers: 1 messages, 0 services
DEBUG variable catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS: /opt/ros/hydro/include;/usr/include
DEBUG variable OpenNI_INCLUDE_DIRS: /usr/include/ni
DEBUG variable GLUT_INCLUDE_DIRS:
DEBUG variable orocos_kdl_INCLUDE_DIRS: /usr/include/eigen3;/opt/ros/hydro/include
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/rical/ros_kinect/build

##### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/rical/ros_kinect/build"

Scanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] [  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target skeleton_tracker
Scanning dependencies of target skeleton_markers_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] [  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 14%] Scanning dependencies of target skeleton_markers_generate_messages_lisp
Generating C++ code from skeleton_markers/Skeleton.msg
Scanning dependencies of target skeleton_markers_generate_messages_py
[ 28%] [ 42%] Generating Lisp code from skeleton_markers/Skeleton.msg
Generating Python from MSG skeleton_markers/Skeleton
[ 57%] [ 57%] Built target skeleton_markers_generate_messages_lisp
Generating Python msg **init**.py for skeleton_markers
[ 57%] Built target skeleton_markers_generate_messages_py
[ 57%] Built target skeleton_markers_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target skeleton_markers_generate_messages
[ 57%] Built target skeleton_markers_generate_messages
[ 71%] [ 85%] [100%] Building CXX object skeleton_markers/CMakeFiles/skeleton_tracker.dir/src/KinectDisplay.cpp.o
Building CXX object skeleton_markers/CMakeFiles/skeleton_tracker.dir/src/KinectController.cpp.o
Building CXX object skeleton_markers/CMakeFiles/skeleton_tracker.dir/src/skeleton_tracker.cpp.o
In file included from /home/rical/ros_kinect/src/skeleton_markers/src/KinectController.h:5:0,
from /home/rical/ros_kinect/src/skeleton_markers/src/KinectController.cpp:4:
/usr/include/ni/XnCppWrapper.h: In member function ‘XnStatus xn::SkeletonCapability::RegisterCalibrationCallbacks(xn::SkeletonCapability::CalibrationStart, xn::SkeletonCapability::CalibrationEnd, void*, void*&)’:
/usr/include/ni/XnCppWrapper.h:7058:165: warning: call to ‘xnRegisterCalibrationCallbacks’ declared with attribute warning: This function is deprecated: Please use RegisterToCalibrationStart/Complete [enabled by default]
/usr/include/ni/XnCppWrapper.h: In member function ‘XnStatus xn::PoseDetectionCapability::RegisterToPoseCallbacks(xn::PoseDetectionCapability::PoseDetection, xn::PoseDetectionCapability::PoseDetection, void*, void*&)’:
/usr/include/ni/XnCppWrapper.h:7468:161: warning: call to ‘xnRegisterToPoseCallbacks’ declared with attribute warning: This function is deprecated: Please use PoseDetected and/or OutOfPose callbacks [enabled by default]
/usr/include/ni/XnCppWrapper.h: In member function ‘XnStatus xn::Context::InitFromXmlFile(const XnChar*, xn::EnumerationErrors*)’:
/usr/include/ni/XnCppWrapper.h:9533:114: warning: call to ‘xnInitFromXmlFile’ declared with attribute warning: This function is deprecated: Please use xnInitFromXmlFileEx() instead [enabled by default]
/usr/include/ni/XnCppWrapper.h: In member function ‘XnStatus xn::Context::OpenFileRecording(const XnChar*)’:
/usr/include/ni/XnCppWrapper.h:9548:61: warning: call to ‘xnContextOpenFileRecording’ declared with attribute warning: This function is deprecated: Please use xnContextOpenFileRecordingEx() instead [enabled by default]
/home/rical/ros_kinect/src/skeleton_markers/src/KinectController.cpp: In member function ‘int KinectController::init(const char*, bool)’:
/home/rical/ros_kinect/src/skeleton_markers/src/KinectController.cpp:108:46: warning: call to ‘xn::Context::OpenFileRecording’ declared with attribute warning: This function is deprecated: Use other overload! [enabled by default]
/home/rical/ros_kinect/src/skeleton_markers/src/KinectController.cpp:117:44: warning: call to ‘xn::Context::InitFromXmlFile’ declared with attribute warning: This function is deprecated: Use other overload! [enabled by default]
/home/rical/ros_kinect/src/skeleton_markers/src/KinectController.cpp:137:158: warning: call to ‘xn::SkeletonCapability::RegisterCalibrationCallbacks’ declared with attribute warning: This function is deprecated: Please use RegisterToCalibrationStart/Complete [enabled by default]
/home/rical/ros_kinect/src/skeleton_markers/src/KinectController.cpp:147:115: warning: call to ‘xn::PoseDetectionCapability::RegisterToPoseCallbacks’ declared with attribute warning: This function is deprecated: Please use RegisterToPoseDetected/RegisterToOutOfPose instead [enabled by default]
Linking CXX executable /home/rical/ros_kinect/devel/lib/skeleton_markers/skeleton_tracker
[100%] Built target skeleton_tracker

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/144306/error-on-skeleton-markers/) by [pinocchio](https://answers.ros.org/users/13681/pinocchio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2014-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for the bug report.  I was missing a step in the installation instructions: you have to first 'cd skeleton_markers' before doing 'git checkout hydro-devel'.  Here are the corrected instructions and I have also updated the ROS Wiki page:

```
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src (change to match your catkin workspace directory)
$ git clone https://github.com/pirobot/skeleton_markers.git
$ cd skeleton_markers
$ git checkout hydro-devel
$ cd ~/catkin_ws
$ catkin_make
```

--patrick

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2014-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pinocchio](https://answers.ros.org/users/13681/pinocchio/) on 2014-03-26**:
Hi @Pi Robot, Thanks for your help. However, using this new instruction makes skeleton_marker does not work. I mean when I use the old one, Method Two on instruction works, although error occurs on git checkout hydro-devel. When I add cd skeleton_markers and git checkout hydro-devel following the new instruction, error of git checkout hydro-devel disappears, but error appears on catkin_make. Because there is some limit, I revise my question and update the log there. Many thanks.

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2014-03-26**:
Hi @pinocchio, it looks like you have a problem in your beginner_tutorials package.  Try moving that package out of your catkin_ws/src folder for now, then remove the devel, build and install subdirectories beneath catkin_ws so you are starting clean, then re-run catkin_make.

**Comment by [pinocchio](https://answers.ros.org/users/13681/pinocchio/) on 2014-03-26**:
Hi @Pi Robot, I initiate a new workspace, and install skeleton_markers in it. However the same error occurs. The log is posted on the question. Thanks again for your help.

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2014-03-26**:
Looks like you might be missing the Glut libraries.  Please try 'sudo apt-get install freeglut3 freeglut3-dev' and then re-run catkin_make.

**Comment by [pinocchio](https://answers.ros.org/users/13681/pinocchio/) on 2014-03-26**:
Thank you very much @Pi Robot. It works now, except a warning shown. I think it is related to the depth_registration. You know I cannot enable it to show the registered RGBD image. I post the problem here. http://answers.ros.org/question/143871/no-register-data-from-kinect/